# Ruby slow startup performance on VMware

Tags: ruby, jruby, vmware

my old netbook (AMD C-60) when starting Sinatra apps would starts in 5-7 seconds (Ruby), 23-24 seconds (JRuby)

> OS (netbook): 32-bit Arch Linux 3.4.62-1 i686 PAE (2GB RAM)

my developmen PC (AMD A8-6600K) starts at 1-2 seconds (Ruby), 12-16 seconds (JRuby)

> OS (pc): 32-bit Arch Linux 3.11.1-1 i686 PAE (8GB RAM)

When i add vmware on my development PC, starts at 0.9-2 seconds (Ruby), 7 seconds (JRuby)

> Guest OS (vm-pc): 32-bit Arch Linux 3.11.1-2 i686 (1.5GB RAM)

when using 32-bit guest under 64-bit VMware under (i3-3220, that should be many times faster than my old netbook), it starts in **45-46** seconds (Ruby), and **30-37** seconds (JRuby)..

> Guest OS (vm-i3): 32-bit Arch Linux 3.11.1-2 i686 (1.5GB RAM)
>
> Host OS: 64-bit Ubuntu Linux 3.8.0.19 x86_64 13.04 (2GB RAM, only running Unity, VMware and gnome-terminal)

When running a single script (generating 12MB of data to database), the performance was normal:

```
real/user/sys
netbook: ruby: 4:25/2:13/0:02 jruby: 13:21/11:46/0:09
pc:      ruby: 1:39/0:31/0:05 jruby:  3:52/ 3:38/0:03
vm-pc:   ruby: 0:40/0:31/0:06 jruby:  3:25/ 3:12/0:02
vm-i3:   ruby: 1:18/0:21/0:05 jruby:  3:16/ 2:19/0:35
```

The configuration:

```
Ruby: using Thin web server, ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]

JRuby: using Trinidad web server, jruby -v
jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on OpenJDK Client VM 1.7.0_40-b31 +indy [linux-i386]
```

what are the possibilities the cause of this startup slowness on vm-i3?

Comment: you should start by disabling invoke dynamic (gets enabled on JDK 1.7.0_40 but is known to cause trouble and performance degradation) ... try starting `jruby` with **-Xcompile.invokedynamic=false**

Comment: thanks, it works faster on the script `2:17/1:33/0:02` and starts faster, about `6s` on my PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on `/etc/hosts` file, forgot to add a line containing localhost/hostname

Answer (score 0):

Another thing which may slow ruby down on startup is the *rubygems* module. If you do not need to load gems, you can speed up startup by running ruby with the `--disable-gems` option.

If you later decide you want to load gems, a simple `require 'rubygems'` above the `require 'some_gem'` line suffices.